# Convert multiple row from one row based on specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert from one row to multiple row based on specific character
I copied a script from someone which was working with his/her example but not working for me which is as below

```
;WITH tmp(NOTEINDX, DataItem, TXTFIELD) AS
(
    SELECT
        NOTEINDX,

        LEFT(TXTFIELD, CHARINDEX('#', TXTFIELD + '#') - 1),
        STUFF(TXTFIELD, 1, CHARINDEX('#', TXTFIELD + '#'), '')
    FROM SY03900
    UNION all

    SELECT
        NOTEINDX,

        LEFT(TXTFIELD, CHARINDEX('#', TXTFIELD + '#') - 1),
        STUFF(TXTFIELD, 1, CHARINDEX(',', TXTFIELD + '#'), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        TXTFIELD > ''
)

SELECT
    NOTEINDX,

    DataItem
FROM tmp
ORDER BY NOTEINDX
```

However I am getting below error

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 
Thanks,
Hatim

Comment: You need to cast the text field to varchar() fields, stuff() won't work on text fields